# why is there a gap between the carpet tack strip and the wall?

Tags: carpet

This house was built in 1951.   The house was "flipped" and the previous owner put in builder grade carpet with no carpet pad.

When I pulled up the carpet observed this odd gap between the carpet tack strip and the wall.  It looks like someone removed a strip of the concrete foundation.  The strip is about 3/4 inch deep and 1.5 inch wide.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before?

[image: Carpet 1] [image: Carpet 2]

Comment: Apparently something has changed over the years. Is it causing a problem somehow?

Comment: A tack strip is normally placed 0.5 to 0.75 inch from the wall so the carpet and pad can slip under the base or shoe moldings. Is yours different from that?

Answer (score 3):

Usually the tack strips are away from the wall to provide room for the carpet to go over the tacks then under the mouldings. It looks like your mouldings are flush on the wall but that could just be my phone not providing enough resolution.

Comment: You're right, of course, but it looks like the gap is up around 2".

Answer (score 1):

I think I see a carpet pad there by the way.   To answer your question, yes I have a seen something like that before.  It was leftover from the 2x lumber that was used to build the form for the concrete that was used to level the floor.